# RemoveAt(i) does not remove

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

When I call removeAt(i), it doesn't remove at specified index. How should I do to remove form array? [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fdb6ru?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="driverInfoForm">
<div class="row" formArrayName="nameDriver">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 d-flex" [formGroupName]="i"
  *ngFor="let driver of nameDriver; let i=index">
  <label>{{i+1}}.Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name{{i}}"  formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="nameDriver[i].name"><br/>
  <label>{{i+1}}.Owner Id</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ownerId" name="ownerId{{i}}" inputmode="numeric" dashFormat formControlName="ownerId" maxLength="14">
  <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" >
  <div class="form-group mb-0" *ngIf="i !== 0">
    
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeDriver(i)">
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
  
    <button *ngIf="i >= 0 && i < 1" type="button" [hidden]="nameDriver.length > 3" (click)="addDriver()" class="btn btn-primary">
      Add
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Component

```
removeDriver(i: number) {

    const control = <FormArray>this.driverInfoForm.controls['nameDriver'];
    control.removeAt(i);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use reactive form and template driven form together.

First remove ngModel from html template.

Second rely on FormArray control instead of nameDriver array value

Define nameDriverControl getter inside ts file and use this to iterate form array on html instead of nameDriver

**component.ts**

```
get nameDriverControl(){
    return this.driverInfoForm.get('nameDriver') as FormArray;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="driverInfoForm">
  <div class="row" formArrayName="nameDriver">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 d-flex" [formGroupName]="i"
      *ngFor="let driver of nameDriverControl.controls; let i=index">
      <label>{{i+1}}.Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name{{i}}"  formControlName="name" ><br/>
      <label>{{i+1}}.Owner Id</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ownerId" name="ownerId{{i}}" inputmode="numeric" dashFormat formControlName="ownerId" maxLength="14">
      <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
        <div class="form-group mb-0" *ngIf="i !== 0">

          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeDriver(i)">
      Delete
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2">

          <button *ngIf="i >= 0 && i < 1" type="button" [hidden]="nameDriver.length > 3" (click)="addDriver()" class="btn btn-primary">
      Add
    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wzteqt?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the OP's problem, but this question is the top search result currently, so I'll put this here in case any one else runs into a weird state issue like I did.

Remember that `removeAt` emits an event that will trigger `valueChanges` to fire. This was causing, indirectly due to a listener, the array to be immediately repopulated due to another bug.

The fix for me was to fix the listener so it didn't needlessly repopulate the array, but, depending on your circumstance, preventing the event from firing in the first place may be necessary:

```
const control = <FormArray>this.driverInfoForm.controls['nameDriver'];
control.removeAt(i, { emitEvent: false });
```